# Migrate marketing list from CRM 4.0 to CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

i want to export marketing lists from CRM 4.0 and import it to CRM Online. Do you have any ideas how i can do it? I can migrate marketing list but not a marketing list members

Comment: I found solution. Just used Microsoft Integration Services for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Integration Services for copy marketing list members from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2013 Online. There is custom Connector for that i used [SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm)